# Struts2 or spring open file in WEB-inf

Tags: java, spring, file, struts2

I am trying to do first web app with Struts2. How to *write* data to text file, where it could be placed? I'm using Struts2 with Spring (Tomcat7 and eclipse).

Comment: It would be independent of the framework you choose ... you jave to place the logic in the Action or Controller .. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Writing a file would not be different to writing a file in regular Java. As @user1428716 points out, your code would have to be locate in an `Action` or `Controller`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where does tomcat store my files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552058/where-does-tomcat-store-my-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can write data to a text file anywhere on your file system as long as you have its full path and write privileges, regardless of Struts2 or Spring.